# Red to-date doesn't work with AAAA.MM.JJ

Tags: rebol, red

This code snippet works on Rebol:

```
to-date "2017.08.29"
```

but it doesn't work on Red

Looking at the source seems the same. So why it doesn't behave the same way ? What to do ?

Comment: Red could support that format too. Please open a wish ticket for it on Red's github repo.

Comment: @DocKimbel ok thanks will create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>> load replace/all "2017.08.29" "." "-"
== 29-Aug-2017
```